# Resolving broken unmet dependency with libc6 on mint 20.2

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, software-installation, upgrade

I work at a university where I am forced into the Microsoft ecosystem.  Ugh.  Given that reality, I'd like to install the linux OneDrive client.

https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

I am getting the following error and I can't resolve it.

```
$ sudo apt install onedrive
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 onedrive : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
            Depends: libphobos2-ldc-shared94 (>= 1:1.24.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**System and How I got here**

I am running Linux Mint 20.2 with kernel 5.11:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20.2
Release:    20.2
Codename:   uma

$ uname -r
5.11.0-46-generic
```

I followed the installation instructions for the OneDrive client here:

https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md

noting that step 3 says to follow the Ubuntu 20.04 installation.  When I do, I get the error list at the top of this post.

Typical `apt` commands show that I am up to date:

```
$ sudo apt-get update         
Ign:1 http://packages.linuxmint.com uma InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                
Hit:3 http://packages.linuxmint.com uma Release                                                                                                             
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                   
Hit:5 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease                                                                                      
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:8 http://dell.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                                                                                                     
Get:9 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ InRelease [3,622 B]                                                                        
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                    
Hit:12 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                        
Hit:13 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_21.04 ./ InRelease
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Fetched 340 kB in 2s (168 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done

$ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get autoremove -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get autoclean -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

If you wonder about the one non-upgraded package, its snapd:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy | tail
<omitted stuff>
Pinned packages:
     snapd -> 2.51.1+20.04ubuntu2 with priority -10
     snapd -> 2.49.2+20.04 with priority -10
     snapd -> 2.48.3+20.04 with priority -10
     snapd -> 2.44.3+20.04 with priority -10
```

I get that I have 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 installed.

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy libc6
libc6:
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

And I get that in need a more recent version of `libc6`.  I assume that my current version of libc6 is included in `2.31-0ubuntu9.2`

Two questions:

- Why does `apt` report `2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed."  It seems to me it's already installed.
- What how can I resolve this issue? (Or do I just live with inefficient access to OneDrive by browser or running a virtual
  Windoze machine)

I'm sure I could dig around and find a way to upgrade `libc6`, but I'm wondering whether that's wise, given that it's a pretty foundational library.

Thanks for any information you can provide.  I especially appreciate explanations of suggested solutions so I can continue to learn to effectively manage my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `onedrive` on linux mint by:

###### Enabling Universe repository:

Onedrive is packaged under the `universe` repository.  You can install it through:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install onedrive
```

###### From OpenSuSE Build Service repository:

You don't need to upgrade `libc6`. You need to use the instruction for [Ubuntu 20.04](https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md#distribution-ubuntu-2004) instead of 21.04:

```
echo 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_20.04/ ./' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/onedrive.list
wget -qO - https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_20.04/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install onedrive
```

Comment: Wait a minute...  Are you telling me I actually need to read the instructions more carefully?  Ye gods! As a note for posterity, I removed to 21.04 repository I had linked (https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=248573) and then followed the instructions from GAD3R.  I have yet to test, but the installation went smoothly.  Hat's off, @GAD3R, for patiently and kindly pointing out my mental lapse.